# Eliminar las listas vacías de la columna de un dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tablas

Tengo una columna con una lista de valores, con registros vacíos:

```
df.Answers.head()
0    ['In next 3 months', 'In next 6 months', 'In n...
1    ["Doctor's availability in hotel", 'Ventilator...
2    ['Buffet breakfast with social distancing', 'B...
3    ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', ...
4                                                 ['']
```

Me gustaría deshacerme de ellas. Entonces intenté:

```
def remove_empty_arrays(answers):
...     if answers in [[''], ["'"], []]:
...         print("Got an empty bracket")
...         return None
... df.Answers.map(remove_empty_arrays)
```

Pero nunca funciona

Comment: quieres quitar de la columna `Answers`, los valores que suelen aparecer como : `['']` , `["'"]` o `[]`  ? lo que puedes hacer es probar haciendo `answers == []` y agregarle or y las demás condiciones. Te sorprenderá la respuesta de `[] in []`

Comment: @LucasDamian Sí, y especialmente quiero deshacerme de `['']`. Pero incluso de eso no puedo deshacerme.

Comment: Quizás es que la columna Answers no tiene en realidad listas, como aparenta, sino una cadena python cuyo contenido tiene sintaxis de lista. Es decir, que por ejemplo un elemento de esa columna sea la cadena `"[ 'Hello', 'world' ]"` en lugar de la lista `[ 'Hello', 'world' ]`. De hecho me temo que este sea el caso pues si fueran listas "de verdad" pandas no mostraría las comillas alrededor de cada elemento en la misma.

Answer (score 1):

No sé si existe una forma más **Pythonica** de hacerlo, pero se me ocurre esta forma de obtener el resultado que esperas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'URL': ['www1', 'www2', 'www3','www4'], 'QID': [1, 2, 3,4],'Questions':['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3','Q4'],'QType':['Type1', 'Type2', 'Type3','Type4'],'Answers':[['Q1 A1','Q1 A2','Q1 A3'], ['Q2 A1','Q2 A2'], ['Q3A 1','Q3 A2','Q3 A3','Q3 A4'],['']]})
print(df.Answers)
```

Este es el contenido de la columna **`Answers`** inicialmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación convertimos la columna **`Answers`** en una cadena, reemplazo los registros **`''`** con **`NaN`**, eliminamos registros **`NaN's`** y finalmente volvemos a dejar la columna como lista:

```
df['Answers']=df['Answers'].apply(lambda x: "-".join(x)) #convierto la lista de answers en una cadena
df['Answers'] = df['Answers'].replace('', np.nan) # Reemplazo los registros vacíos con NaN
df = df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['Answers']) # Elimino registros con Answers NaN
df['Answers']= df['Answers'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')) # Vuelvo a dejar la columna en tipo Lista

print(df.Answers)
```

Este el resultado de la columna **`Answers`** quitando los registros vacíos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no quieres borrar los registros vacíos, sino reemplazarlos por un valor específico (p.e. 0), reemplaza la línea `df = df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['Answers'])` por  `df['Answers'].fillna(0, inplace=True)`.